# Android kotlin app using exoplayer crashing without error indication

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I am making an app to play local videos using exoplayer. I am using Vivo device for testing. It shows notification for app which responds slowly or crashes. But when this app crashes it does not show any notification. My app crashes with system logs related to C, C++ libraries. I am using exoplayer to play videos in view pager with fragments. App crashes on swipping viewpager. I want to find and resolve the error in the following crash:

```
--------- beginning of crash
2020-12-02 18:08:54.143 12237-12341/com.muhana.triplet A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 12341 (hwuiTask2), pid 12237 (.muhana.triplet)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.229 537-2806/? E/MtkOmxVdecEx: [0xe963e000] @@ OMX_GoogleAndroidIndexEnableAndroidNativeHandle: invalid port index
2020-12-02 18:08:54.229 537-2806/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setParameter(0xe963e004:MTK.DECODER.AVC, OMX.google.android.index.allocateNativeHandle(0x7f20040e): Output:1 en=0) ERROR: BadParameter(0x80001005)
2020-12-02 18:08:54.234 537-2806/? E/MtkOmxVdecEx: [0xe963e000] MtkOmxVdec::SetConfig Unknown config index: 0x6F800002
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.234 537-2806/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(0xe963e004:MTK.DECODER.AVC, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2020-12-02 18:08:54.235 537-21276/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xe963e004:MTK.DECODER.AVC, ConfigAndroidVendorExtension(0x6f100004)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
2020-12-02 18:08:54.236 537-21276/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(0xe963e004:MTK.DECODER.AVC, ConfigCommonOutputCrop(0x700000f)) ERROR: BadParameter(0x80001005)
2020-12-02 18:08:54.353 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG: Softversion: PD1917F_EX_A_1.24.10
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.353 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG: Time: 2020-12-02 18:08:54
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.353 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.354 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'vivo/1812/1812:8.1.0/O11019/1604650506:user/release-keys'
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.354 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.354 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.354 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG: pid: 12237, tid: 12341, name: hwuiTask2  >>> com.muhana.triplet <<<
2020-12-02 18:08:54.354 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.361 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'Error: Spot pair overflow!!! used 8, total 7'
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.361 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000003035  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.361 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     x4   3200000000000000  x5   3200000000000000  x6   3200000000000000  x7   0000000000008032
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.361 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000083  x9   0000000010000000  x10  0000007e259321d0  x11  0000000000000001
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.361 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000007e259322f0  x13  0000000000000001  x14  ffffffffffffffff  x15  3200000000000000
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.362 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000005f1b7f7fa8  x17  0000007ec4c37e5c  x18  0000000000000001  x19  0000000000002fcd
2020-12-02 18:08:54.362 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000000000003035  x21  0000000000000083  x22  0000007e25932ad0  x23  0000000000000010
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.362 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000007e25933588  x25  0000007e25932740  x26  0000007e25932780  x27  0000000000000007
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.362 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000000000005  x29  0000007e25932210  x30  0000007ec4bec7a0
2020-12-02 18:08:54.362 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007e259321d0  pc   0000007ec4bec7c8  pstate 0000000060000000
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.370 2276-2837/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2276)remove pid error : pids is null
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.410 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.411 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000001d7c8  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+120)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.411 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000007f08  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+296)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.411 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00000000000c09c8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::ShadowTessellator::checkOverflow(int, int, char const*)+68)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.411 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00000000000c6cb8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::SpotShadow::generateTriangleStrip(bool, float, android::uirenderer::Vector2*, int, android::uirenderer::Vector2*, int, android::uirenderer::Vector3 const*, int, android::uirenderer::VertexBuffer&, android::uirenderer::Vector2 const&)+512)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.411 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000000000c6a28  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::SpotShadow::createSpotShadow(bool, android::uirenderer::Vector3 const&, float, android::uirenderer::Vector3 const*, int, android::uirenderer::Vector3 const&, android::uirenderer::VertexBuffer&)+1524)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.411 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000000c0710  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::ShadowTessellator::tessellateSpotShadow(bool, android::uirenderer::Vector3 const*, int, android::uirenderer::Vector3 const&, android::uirenderer::Matrix4 const&, android::uirenderer::Vector3 const&, int, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, android::uirenderer::VertexBuffer&)+472)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.411 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00000000000c8658  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::tessellateShadows(android::uirenderer::Matrix4 const*, android::uirenderer::Rect const*, bool, SkPath const*, android::uirenderer::Matrix4 const*, android::uirenderer::Matrix4 const*, android::uirenderer::Vector3 const&, float, android::uirenderer::VertexBuffer&, android::uirenderer::VertexBuffer&)+800)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.411 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00000000000ca5c8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::ShadowProcessor::onProcess(android::sp<android::uirenderer::Task<android::uirenderer::Pair<android::uirenderer::VertexBuffer*, android::uirenderer::VertexBuffer*>>> const&)+108)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.412 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 0000000000077104  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::TaskProcessor<bool>::process(android::sp<android::uirenderer::TaskBase> const&)+72)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.412 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 0000000000084518  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::TaskManager::WorkerThread::threadLoop()+140)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.412 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00000000000114b0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+280)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.412 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00000000000aba2c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.412 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00000000000686b0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
        2020-12-02 18:08:54.412 12649-12649/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 000000000001edbc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
        2020-12-02 18:08:55.131 2276-20835/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2276)remove pid error : pids is null
        2020-12-02 18:08:55.131 2276-20835/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2276)remove pid error : pids is null
        2020-12-02 18:08:55.131 2276-20835/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2276)remove pid error : pids is null
        2020-12-02 18:08:55.134 2276-20835/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2276)remove pid error : pids is null
        2020-12-02 18:08:55.818 538-538/? E/Situation: processEvent, handle:90, flush_action:0
        2020-12-02 18:08:56.233 538-1092/? E/Situation: processEvent, handle:90, flush_action:0
        2020-12-02 18:08:56.524 2276-20835/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2276)remove pid error : pids is null
        2020-12-02 18:08:56.525 2276-20835/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2276)remove pid error : pids is null
        2020-12-02 18:08:56.856 538-1092/? E/Situation: processEvent, handle:90, flush_action:0
        2020-12-02 18:08:56.993 12659-12659/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/aee_dumpstate
2020-12-02 18:08:57.018 863-1165/? E/JniVivoSensorOperationUtils: Java_com_sensoroperate_VivoSensorOperationUtils_jniVivoSensorOperationUtilsInt
2020-12-02 18:08:57.043 12660-12660/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/ls
2020-12-02 18:08:57.064 538-538/? E/Situation: processEvent, handle:90, flush_action:0
        2020-12-02 18:08:57.080 12661-12661/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/xbin/showmap
2020-12-02 18:08:57.082 12661-12661/? E/AEE_AED: copy_process: execvp /system/xbin/showmap failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:08:57.093 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /proc/m4u/mva to SYS_M4UMVA failed(20), Not a directory
2020-12-02 18:08:57.094 12659-12659/? E/AEE_AED: dest file /data/aee_exp/temp/db.JjDSJ1/SYS_MMPROFILE, error is Bad address 
2020-12-02 18:08:57.094 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /sys/kernel/debug/mmprofile/buffer to SYS_MMPROFILE failed(14), Bad address
2020-12-02 18:08:57.095 12662-12662/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/logcat
2020-12-02 18:08:57.145 12664-12664/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/logcat
2020-12-02 18:08:57.426 537-12609/? E/MtkOmxVdecEx: ## [ERROR, 110] MtkOmxVdecDecodeThread() line: 1151 WAIT timeout...
        2020-12-02 18:08:57.774 12666-12666/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/logcat
2020-12-02 18:08:58.292 2276-2837/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2276)remove pid error : pids is null
        2020-12-02 18:08:58.321 12682-12682/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/top
2020-12-02 18:08:58.617 12668-12668/? E/ANRManager: mPackageName = com.android.camera, Get anr service = android.app.anr.IANRManager$Stub$Proxy@b236804
2020-12-02 18:08:59.040 8034-12694/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
        2020-12-02 18:08:59.219 537-12646/? E/MtkOmxVdecEx: ## [ERROR, 110] MtkOmxVdecDecodeThread() line: 1151 WAIT timeout...
        2020-12-02 18:08:59.239 537-12645/? E/MtkOmxVdecEx: ## [ERROR, 110] HandleStateSet() line: 7306 WAIT timeout...
        2020-12-02 18:09:00.117 2294-2334/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/bbkcore/theme/icons/dynamic_icon/com.android.BBKClock/res/drawable-sw360dp-xhdpi/clock_hour.png (No such file or directory)
        2020-12-02 18:09:00.128 2294-2334/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/bbkcore/theme/icons/dynamic_icon/com.android.BBKClock/res/drawable-sw360dp-xhdpi/clock_minute.png (No such file or directory)
        2020-12-02 18:09:00.144 2294-2334/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/bbkcore/theme/icons/dynamic_icon/com.android.BBKClock/res/drawable-sw360dp-xhdpi/clock_dial.png (No such file or directory)
        2020-12-02 18:09:00.146 2294-2334/? E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/bbkcore/theme/icons/dynamic_icon/com.android.BBKClock/res/drawable-sw360dp-xhdpi/clock_dial_center.png (No such file or directory)
        2020-12-02 18:09:00.270 2276-2837/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2276)remove pid error : pids is null
        2020-12-02 18:09:00.378 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /proc/slabinfo to SYS_SLAB_INFO failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:00.380 12696-12696/? E/AEE_AED: save_process_output_to_fd: execv /system/bin/netcfg failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:00.389 12697-12697/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/dmesg
2020-12-02 18:09:00.539 12698-12698/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/ps
2020-12-02 18:09:01.681 12700-12700/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/df
2020-12-02 18:09:01.701 12701-12701/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/mount
2020-12-02 18:09:01.739 12702-12702/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/lshal
2020-12-02 18:09:01.798 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /data/anr/traces.txt to NE_JBT_TRACES failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:01.799 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: append_file: Copy /data/anr/mtk_traces.txt to NE_JBT_TRACES failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:01.807 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /data/anr/SF_RTT/rtt_dump_1.txt to SF_RTT_DUMP1 failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:01.807 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /data/SF_RTT/rtt_dump.txt to SF_RTT_DUMP failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:01.807 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /data/SF_RTT/rtt_dump_1.txt to SF_RTT_DUMP1 failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:01.808 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /proc/mali/memory_usage to SYS_MALI_MEM_USED failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:01.808 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /sys/kernel/debug/binder/page_used to SYS_BINDER_MEM_USED failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:01.837 12705-12705/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/lsof
2020-12-02 18:09:02.589 2276-2837/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (2276)remove pid error : pids is null
        2020-12-02 18:09:03.812 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /proc/driver/usktrk_aee to SYS_PROC_USKTRK failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.812 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /sys/power/mtkpasr/execstate to SYS_MTKPASR_INFO failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.820 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /sys/kernel/debug/cpuhvfs/dbg_repo to SYS_CPUHVFS_REPO failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.823 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /sys/kernel/debug/fuseio/log to SYS_FUSEIO_LOG failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.840 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /sys/kernel/debug/emi_mbw/dump_buf to SYS_EMI_MBW_DUMP_BUF failed(13), Permission denied
2020-12-02 18:09:03.850 12659-12659/? E/AEE_AED: print_dram_log: mrdump_dramlog_get failed
2020-12-02 18:09:03.850 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /sys/kernel/debug/page_owner_slim to SYS_PAGE_OWNER_SLIM failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.850 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /sys/power/mtkdcs/debug to SYS_MTKDCS_DEBUG failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.850 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /proc/isp_p2/isp_p2_dump to SYS_ISP_P2_DUMP failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.850 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /sys/power/vcorefs/vcore_debug to SYS_VCORE_DEBUG failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.850 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /sys/power/vcorefs/opp_table to SYS_OPP_TABLE failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.851 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /proc/ufs_debug to SYS_STORAGE_DEBUG_UFS failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.914 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /proc/mtk_es_reg_dump to SYS_MTK_ES_REG_DUMP failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.914 12659-12659/? E/AEE_DUMPSTATE: copy_file: Copy /sys/kernel/debug/vpu/device_dbg to SYS_VPU_DEVICE_DBG failed(2), No such file or directory
2020-12-02 18:09:03.932 12707-12707/? E/AEE_AED: execute /system/bin/aee_archive
2020-12-02 18:09:03.936 571-571/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_07
2020-12-02 18:09:04.002 863-1107/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '3a36a46 com.muhana.triplet/com.muhana.triplet.video.VideoActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
        2020-12-02 18:09:04.003 537-21276/? E/OMXNodeInstance: !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
        2020-12-02 18:09:04.003 537-2806/? E/OMXNodeInstance: !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
        2020-12-02 18:09:04.004 537-4753/? E/OMXNodeInstance: !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
        2020-12-02 18:09:04.012 537-21310/? E/OMXNodeInstance: !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
        2020-12-02 18:09:04.013 537-13979/? E/OMXNodeInstance: !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
        2020-12-02 18:09:04.016 863-1107/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '87ff4b8 com.muhana.triplet/com.muhana.triplet.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
        2020-12-02 18:09:04.925 863-2403/? E/TouchFilter: setTouchFilter LOG Enable prameter: 0
        2020-12-02 18:09:04.959 1482-6985/? E/ProxCoverNoticeService: monitor view is null, no need to update minimum
2020-12-02 18:09:05.021 4591-4760/? E/_V_AppStatisticManager: addLruPkg pkgName = com.muhana.triplet
2020-12-02 18:09:05.042 387-469/? E/IMGSRV: :0: GrallocTestAlloc: Invalid color format (-3)
2020-12-02 18:09:05.042 863-2402/? E/GraphicBufferAllocator: Failed to allocate (101 x 101) layerCount 1 format -3 usage 2: 7
        2020-12-02 18:09:05.066 4591-4760/? E/_V_AppStatisticManager: addLruPkg pkgName = com.bbk.launcher2
2020-12-02 18:09:05.068 1482-6985/? E/ProxCoverNoticeService: monitor view is null, no need to update fullscreen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in some devices, you can't use multiple instances of surface view and there is a minimum of that.
you should have a singleton exoplayer and prepare the player in idle time of scrolling.
you can't have multiple instances of exoplayer in each cell of recycler view or viewpager.

Comment: I am using three exoplayer instances. Is that exceeding the limit?

Answer (score 1):

This can be a device specific issue. Vivo devices has number of issues with multiple applications. Try this with another device It will work fine.